# Node.js Sodium install failure

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, libsodium

I have been getting some errors when trying to install Sodium and a couple others. They all have the same error (with different names of course). I tried to solve it myself but ended up not being able too. It also happens with node-opus and it also happens with hammerandchisel/erlpack. But with erlpack instead of it saying,

> sodium@2.0.3 install: `node install.js --install`

it says

> erlpack@0.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install sodium

> sodium@2.0.3 preinstall C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\sodium
> node install.js --preinstall

MS Version: 2015
Preinstall Mode
Download libsodium.lib
MS Version: 2015
Platform Tool is v140
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/x64/Release/v140/dynamic/libsodium.dll
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/x64/Release/v140/dynamic/libsodium.exp
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/x64/Release/v140/dynamic/libsodium.lib
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/x64/Release/v140/dynamic/libsodium.pdb
Libs for version v140 downloaded.
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/core.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_aead_aes256gcm.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_auth.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_auth_hmacsha256.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_auth_hmacsha512.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_auth_hmacsha512256.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_box.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_core_hchacha20.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_core_hsalsa20.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_core_salsa20.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_core_salsa2012.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_core_salsa208.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_generichash.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_generichash_blake2b.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_hash.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_hash_sha256.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_hash_sha512.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_int32.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_int64.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_onetimeauth.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_onetimeauth_poly1305.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_pwhash.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_pwhash_argon2i.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_scalarmult.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_scalarmult_curve25519.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_secretbox.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_shorthash.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_shorthash_siphash24.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_sign.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_sign_ed25519.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_sign_edwards25519sha512batch.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_stream.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_stream_chacha20.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_stream_salsa20.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_stream_salsa2012.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_stream_salsa208.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_stream_xsalsa20.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_uint16.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_uint32.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_uint64.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_uint8.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_verify_16.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_verify_32.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/crypto_verify_64.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/export.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/randombytes.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/randombytes_salsa20_random.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/randombytes_sysrandom.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/runtime.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/utils.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium/version.h
Download: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paixaop/libsodium-bin/master/1.0.11/include/sodium.h
Include files downloaded.
Prebuild steps completed. Binary libsodium distribution installed in ./deps/build

> sodium@2.0.3 install C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\sodium
> node install.js --install

MS Version: 2015
Install Mode

C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\sodium>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Wicked\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Wicked\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\sodium) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Wicked\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Wicked\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\sodium
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\sodium\install.js:287
            throw new Error(cmdLine + ' exited with code ' + code);
            ^

Error: node-gyp rebuild exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\sodium\install.js:287:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN wunked@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN wunked@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sodium@2.0.3 install: `node install.js --install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sodium@2.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Wicked\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-30T01_24_53_611Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried updating node-gyp? I got the same error a while back on a different package and it fixed it. https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm's-bundled-node-gyp

Comment: Just tried, still didn't work.